# FFMPEG (Input 8K AAC -> (AAC FLV) youtube streaming noise

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flv, noise, aac

Hello I run a streaming encoder for a non profit cause. Chosen FFMPEG as it's very simple and doing the job near perfectly however the audio is noisy popping and cracking. Video is crystal clear.

ffmpeg version N-86950-g1bef008 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)

Here is my command.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i $RTSP_SRC -vcodec copy -af "volume=12dB" -ar 8000 -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$DEST_KEY
```

However when I just play the stream the noise levels are quite acceptable.

```
ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp -i $RTSP_SRC
```

What I have tried so far.

- Change input audio sampling from 8K to 16K (that's all is supported currently). It made the noise problem much worse. I can't change it to a native FLV sampling(44100 or 22050 or 11025) at least not yet, the integrated rtsp stream does not support it.)
- My working theory is during resampling stream noise is getting boosted. So to eliminate that I tried audio copy codec even then there is no significant improvement.

Comment: Look at the [**FLV specifications PDF**](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flv/pdfs/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf). The audio is expected to be in these supported rates: `5.5-kHz` or `11-kHz` or `22-kHz` or `44-kHz` (for AAC the muxer will write 3 (meaning 44khz) but can still add audio bytes of a different supported rate..

Comment: Why not provide a short few seconds example clip (can even just film the floor) to hear how your audio is "noise"? Hiss could be by low bit-depth, stutter could be by slow encoding, overlapping could be by missing audio-frames or wrong timestamps etc... What format is audio input (if mic, then what is its samplerate? bitdepth? stereo? etc)?

Comment: Input #0, aac, from 'output-audio.aac':
  Duration: 00:11:48.13, bitrate: 42 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 42 kb/s .  I kind of did some further inverstigation. If I write down the bit stream to a file @ 44.1K the noise levels are same. So assuming ffmpeg is streaming same bytes to youtube there is not much to blame ffmpeg at this point. However when youtube server re-encodes the noise gets boosted.

Answer (score 0):

-af "equalizer=f=100:t=h:width=200:g=-64" Suppressing this frequency band cut all the crackling / popping noise for me.